# How to convert a namedtuple into a list of values and preserving the order of properties?

Tags: python

```
from collections import namedtuple
Gaga = namedtuple('Gaga', ['id', 'subject', 'recipient'])
g = Gaga(id=1, subject='hello', recipient='Janitor')
```

I want to be able to obtain this list (which preserves the order of the properties):

```
[1, 'hello', 'Janitor']
```

I could create this list myself manually but there must be an easier way.
I tried:

```
g._asdict().values()
```

but the properties are not in the order I want.

Comment: A named tuple already is a sequence of values (just like a list).  What's not working?  `g[0]== 1 and g[1]=='subject and g[2]='recipient'`.  Since it already behaves much like a list, what else do you need?

Comment: @S.Lott THANK YOU SO MUCH, I feel so stupid for forgetting that it's still a tuple, I was thinking of it as a dictionary -_-

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Why not just `list`?

```
>>> list(g)
[1, 'hello', 'Janitor']
```